# ormSession in sqlAlchemy - how to perform a read and update in this case?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Based on the following insert of an entry in the database: how would an update of an existing entry would look like? (so: read from database first; look at that data and manipulate in the memory; update the entry in the database).

Remark: the code is simplifying some things, yes; others are missing. The reason why I ask my question is, that I presently did not find a `read`/`update` example based on the `insert` example below.

```
class Utilities():
    @staticmethod
    def buildDatabaseConnection():
        engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://username:password@localhost/dbname')
        sqlAlchemyDeclarations.SqlAlchemyBaseInstantiated.metadata.bind = engine

        DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        Utilities.ormSession = DBSession()

    @staticmethod
    def createSomeDummyInstances():
        newEntry = sqlAlchemyDeclarations.Mytable(
        name="the name")
        Utilities.ormSession.add(newProcessingEntry)

        Utilities.ormSession.commit()

Utilities.buildDatabaseConnection()
Utilities.createSomeDummyInstances()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667138/how-to-update-sqlalchemy-row-entry, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699360/flask-sqlalchemy-update-a-rows-information, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081121/sqlalchemy-select-for-update-example

Comment: thanks, that helped already!